# phpmailer enviar email con archivo adjunto por servidor local

Tags: php, phpmailer

hace poco pude encontrar la forma de enviar un correo por medio del local de mi computadora, pero ahora quisiera agregar un archivo adjunto al correo, he visto varios tutoriales pero ninguno va de acorde a mi codigo, mi codigo usa objetos de la clase phpMailer y los tutoriales usan el metodo mail(este no me funciona por problemas al conectar con el mailServer), asi que quisiera que me ayudaran para poder enviar un archivo adjunto usando el codigo que me funciona.
Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    include "class.phpmailer.php";
    include "class.smtp.php";
    $email_user = $_POST["correo"];
    $email_password = $_POST["pass"];
    $the_subject = $_POST["asunto"];
    $address_to = $_POST["remitente"];
    $from_name = $_POST["nombre"];
    $phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
    // ---------- datos de la cuenta de Gmail -------------------------------
    $phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
    $phpmailer->Password = $email_password; 
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // $phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $phpmailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
    $phpmailer->Port = 465;
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username,$from_name);
    $phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to); // recipients email
    $phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject; 
    $phpmailer->Body .="<h1 style='color:#3498db;'>UNIVERSIDAD TE DICE:</h1>";
    $phpmailer->Body .= $_POST["comentario"];
    $phpmailer->Body .= "<p>Fecha y Hora: ".date("d-m-Y h:i:s")."</p>";
    $phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
    $phpmailer->Send();
    ?>
```

utilizo metodo post para que capture informacion de un pequeño formulario, creo que entenderan como trabaja todo eso, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/AdvancedMail), debes usar el método `AddAttachment()`:

```
public function AddAttachment($path,
                              $name = '',
                              $encoding = 'base64',
                              $type = 'application/octet-stream')
```

En tu caso, un caso simple sería algo como

$phpMailer->AddAttachment("/path/to/file/to/attach.extension");

Y el archivo viajaría adjunto con nombre "attach.extension".